# 16.04: I have been trying to dowbload wordpress but there is some problem with my apache2. It is not working

Tags: apache2, 16.04, lamp, wordpress

I have been referring to the following to procedures and whenever i check if my apache2 is functioning it shows an error:

WORDPRESS: http://computerbeginnersguides.com/blog/2016/05/12/install-and-configure-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/

LAMP: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

When i check if apache2 has been installed properly by going to "127.0.0.1" , it shows " Error establishing a database connection"

And later while configuring wordpress in mysql:
    mysql> CREATE USER wordpressuser;
    ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

After trying Deepak's way I get the same error when I continue the process:
[image]

Comment: Could you add the error to your answer?

Comment: @palmerito0 thank you for your reply. i have added the errors

Comment: Try a different password when creating the database? Make it stronger with a mix of uppercase, lowercase, numbers, symbols, etc.

Comment: @palmerito0 Sorry i forgot to mention it does not let me enter the password also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [16.04: Problem installing LAMP and wordpress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780248/16-04-problem-installing-lamp-and-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

Please view this.
[Database Connection Error/Wordpress](https://deepakghugeblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/how-to-solve-the-error-error-while-connecting-to-db/)

Hey if your problem is now with the password.You first have to check your current password policy.If it is set to high(default) set a password with minimum 8 characters,1 capital,1 small letter and at least 1 digit.Other two policies are medium and low but generally it is set to high.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you but I even after i strictly followed the password policiies you have mentioned it still shows an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
If you remember the user created for your Wordpress.Remove the previous one and create a new user as wordpressuser.Follow the following commands.

```
> mysql> ALTER USER 'wordpressuser'@'localhost'
>     -> IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
>     -> AS '*HIGHPOLICYPASSWORD123';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

and try further steps.
Hope it helps.If not please provide me the Screen shot of the terminal.

Comment: I have edited my question with the screenshot

Comment: @Hedwig please try to add your own password conatining atleast 1 small word , 1 capital word ,numbers and total password containing totally 8 letters.