# 16.04: Problem installing LAMP and wordpress

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, lamp, wordpress

ok I have followed the following guide: http://computerbeginnersguides.com/blog/2016/05/12/install-and-configure-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/
But, every time I go to the localhost it says "Error establishing a database connection".

Every time i type 127.0.0.1 it just shows a white page

Every time I use my ip address it asks for username and password....but which username and passowrd do i use?

Answer (score 2):

`vi` (and `vim`) show a `~` at the beginning of empty lines.

This (and the `[New file]`) show that you have a new, blank file in which you're supposed to write your WordPress configuration.

Start writing by Pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> (or the `i` key). When you are finished, just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter Vi's command mode, then press type `:wq` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit (`wq` stands for `write, quit`). To save and *not* quit, type `:w` instead of `:wq` and press <kbd>Insert</kbd> (or `i`) to get back to writing.

Though if you have a GUI, I recommend Gedit (or for `root` access, `gksudo gedit`) for editing files, since it's a *lot* simpler than Vim. If you don't have a GUI, use the `nano` editor (or for `root` access, `sudo nano`).

Comment: For the sake of correctness, most GUI programs wont accept `sudo` anymore, suggest rather using `gksudo` which is in the package called `gksu`.

Comment: @Videonauth Adding.

Comment: @Videonauth Also, is `gksu` installed by default?

Comment: Not sure to be honest i have my 16.04 since beta2, i only remember to have installed it, not sure if it is meanwhile by default.

Comment: @Videonauth Doesn't look like it is -- http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.manifest

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Thank you BUT when I go to http://ifconfi127.0.0.1/wordpress it just doesnt load. Could you please tell me what the problem could be.

Comment: @Hedwig That should be a separate question.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I believe the current recommendation is to use `pkexec` instead of `gksudo`; pkexec should be installed by default on Ubuntu

Comment: But `pkexec gedit` prompts for the password all right, but can't open the X display.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a file called wp-config-sample.php, which is a sample wp-config file.

```
 sudo vi /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
```

Once you're finished editing it:

```
 sudo mv /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

Comment: After editing it the second command shows an error:
    mv: cannot move '/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php' to '/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php': Permission denied

Comment: If you get permission denied, just use sudo

sudo  mv /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php